# How to make a CD update file inaccessable to users if computer model number is not in a database

Tags: batch-file, automation, command, autorun

I am creating a service pack update type CD for my company's computers. We service specific computers in a network, but we do not want the hard work on our service pack updates to be used by outside companies. I have written a batch file script to find the model number of a computer and compare it against our database. This generates a file containing the model number if it was found, and nothing if the model number was not found.

Once the model number is confirmed to be legitimate, I want to autorun the update file. However, if the model number is not found in the database, I want to be able to shut down the CD and make the update file inaccessible to the user.

The scripting I have so far is as follows:

```
IF NOT EXIST <name of generated file> (
Goto :DNEx
) ELSE (
Goto :Exists
)
:Exists
Msg * “The file was found, and the service pack will begin installation.”
Goto :End
```

I feel like right here I need to insert the name of the update file, so that it is run from the CD.

```
:DNEx
Msg * “This service pack is only applicable to <company> devices. The program will now close.”
Goto :End
:End
```

I also feel like right here there needs to be some type of shutdown command that stops the user from being able to run the update file from the CD. However, I don't even know where to begin looking for a command that does this.

Comment: you know, that batchfiles are plain textfiles and everybody can easily read them? Besides that, the command for shutdown is (guess...) `shutdown`. For possible parameters see [shutdown /?](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)

Comment: You are aware that nothing prevents the user from just running your executable without the batch file, right? And that batch files are plain text, so anything you put in them the user can just copy and paste out?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to force the batch file to be the only thing that runs from the CD first, and if it detects the computer as an incorrect user, it terminates the CD from running. If the client tried to start the CD again, it would do the same thing and terminate. If possible, completely in the background where it cannot be edited by the client.

Comment: what should keep them to just mount and read the CD?

Comment: That was why I was asking my question here. I don't know where to begin trying to make the file more secure or inaccessible to users that are not on our network. I understand that they could just mount the CD and use the .exe on it, but I am trying to find a way around that issue.